# Determine login type using AWS Cognito during resume session (Swift)

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to determine the login type during a resume session using AWS Cognito.  My code is based upon the MobileHub sample (below).

I've integrated a name/password mode for user pools (account creation and login) as well as as a Facebook login button which all works perfectly.

I have some logic in my application that needs to behave differently depending on the login type but I can't figure out how to do it.

Anyone done this?

```
    func didFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication, withOptions launchOptions: [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print("didFinishLaunching:")

    // Register the sign in provider instances with their unique identifier
    AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().register(signInProvider: AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance())
    AWSIdentityProfileManager.sharedInstance().register(FacebookIdentityProfile.sharedInstance(), forProviderKey: AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance().identityProviderName)
    AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().register(signInProvider: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance())
    AWSIdentityProfileManager.sharedInstance().register(UserPoolsIdentityProfile.sharedInstance(), forProviderKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().identityProviderName)

    setupAPIGateway()
    setupS3()

    let didFinishLaunching: Bool = AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    if (!isInitialized) {
        AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().resumeSession(completionHandler: { (result: Any?, authState: AWSIdentityManagerAuthState, error: Error?) in
            print("didFinishLaunching Result: \(String(describing: result)) AuthState: \(authState) \n Error:\(String(describing: error))")
            if authState == .authenticated {
                // Facebook or Cognito???
                AWSCognitoUserAuthHelper.getCurrentUserAttribute(name: "sub", completionHandler: { (userid) in
                    // we need to fetch the user
                    ObjectManager.instance.getUser(userid: userid, completionHandler: { (user) in
                        ObjectManager.instance.setCurrentUser(user: user)
                    })
                })
            }
        }) // If you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS here in iOS Simulator, then do Simulator -> "Reset Content and Settings..."
        // This will clear bad auth tokens stored by other apps with the same bundle ID.
        isInitialized = true
    }

    return didFinishLaunching
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to cast to the different identity profile types such as the following:

```
let identityManager = AWSIdentityManager.default()

if let fbIdentityProfile = identityManager.identityProfile as? FacebookIdentityProfile {
    print("didFinishLaunching - Facebook login")
} else if let upIdentityProfile = identityManager.identityProfile as? UserPoolsIdentityProfile {
    print("didFinishLaunching - User Pools login")
}
```

I can model logic in my application around this.  Not sure if there is a cleaner approach using the MobileHub helper classes or AWS APIs but this works.